# How to define a static member of a class in the function?

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-members

Here I have:

```
class X {

public:
    static int shared_arr[];
    static void alloc_and_init() {

        // Since any static variables defined in the function are allocated some space.
        // So can I define X::shared_arr here (using the space the static variable for X::shared_arr)? 
        // I think it would be a convenient way to make an approach of some basic memory allocation and initialization.
    }

};
```

Comment: You should probably spend some time with a good book on C++. Your `shared_arr` member is missing the type, and `[]` is as an array modifier gives an incomplete type which cannot be used in a class definition. From a wider perspective, there are almost guaranteed to be much better solutions for whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The member is a `static` member. I believe you can actually use an incomplete type in the *declaration* of the member.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry. I forgot to type that.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Oh, good, I hadn't thought about that -- makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You will have to define it in exactly one cpp file & outside of any function.

```
int X::shared_arr[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
^^^
```

Note that you are missing the array type.

Comment: I'm confused. The static vars inside functions seems just like ones outside (except the scope area).

Comment: @ymfoi: The scope resolution operator tells the compiler that the array you are initializing is a class member.

Comment: I mean the static vars inside functions look much like the global ones. So I wonder if I can do this in function static vars.

Comment: @ymfoi: I just answered, You can't.If this was allowed, Consider the scenario, What happens if the function was defined but never called? What happens when the static member is used in other places, Does it get defined? What is its state?

Comment: Thx.. Any better way to fit my need?

Comment: @ymfoi: To be honest, I don't completely understand What you are trying to achieve through this? If you could express your intent better I might have a word of advice.

Comment: I'm writing a data structure class and I'd like to allocate the memory statically (All instances of that class are sharing the same memory maintained manually). And I want to keep codes clean and tidy, so I need to work out a way to "pack up" the allocation operations

Comment: @ymfoi: Defining the member as I suggested in the answer still satisfy's your requirement, It will still be a member shared by all the objects of your class.

Comment: Yeah..But my static members are miscellaneous ones, it looks ugly to do this in global scope.